# programmatically set scroll on gridview android

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have to programmatically set the scroll of my gridview.

```
android:scroll="horizontal"
```

Above is setting in xml. I am wondering how about programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation the android:scroll is not available for the Gridview.
Aren't you getting any errors for using it? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

What you can do is calculate the number of columns before hand and set the number of columns of the gridView with [setNumColumns()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns%28int%29).

Them  you set the height to match_parent and only enable the horizontal scrollbar with [setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled%28boolean%29);.